# density in Wasserstein spaces

Tags: measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems, optimal-transport

I am wondering whether the following result is true:

> Let $\mathcal W_p(\mathbb R^d)$ be the Wasserstein space of order $p$ and let $\eta$ and $\gamma$ be two probability measures in $\mathcal W_p(\mathbb R^d)$, such that supp($\eta$) $\subset$ supp($\gamma$). Then there is a sequence of probability measures $(\eta_n)$ that converges to $\eta$ in $\mathcal W_p(\mathbb R^d)$ and such that $\eta_n$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\gamma$, with $\frac{\eta_n}{\gamma}$ being bounded.

It seems to be a well-known result but I was not able to prove it nor to find a reference. Any help and suggestion are appreciated!

Comment: If the reference measure $\gamma$ is Lebesgue measure, then it seems that convolving $\eta$ with the standard mollifier $\rho_\epsilon$ and letting $\epsilon \to 0$ gives you what you need. Lemma 7.1.10 in "Gradient flows in metric spaces and spaces of probability measures" by Ambrosio, proves that we have the convergence and you can also prove that the sequence is absolutely continuous. I don't know about boundedness.